# Is it possible to have different results in CTE clauses in READ COMMITTED isolation level?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the `read committed` isolation level, 2 subsequent select queries in the same transaction can have different results, because there might have been concurrent updates in between the 2 queries:

```
transaction 1: select id from table;
    => returns [1, 2, 3]
transaction 2: delete from table where id = 2;
transaction 1: select id from table;
    => returns [1, 3]
```

What happens if the select queries in transaction 1 are combined in a CTE? Say I have the following dummy query:

```
with
cte_1 as (select id from table),
cte_2 as (select id from table)
select (select count(*) from cte_1, select count(*) from cte_2)
```

Is it now also possible that we get different results if a concurrent update comes between the execution of `cte_1` and `cte_2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every statement is executed atomically and will see a consistent view of the database throughout its runtime. The "two CTEs" are a **single** query so that query also doesn't see any (committed) changes done while its running

The CTE query is equivalent to:

```
select (select count(*) from (select id from table) as cte1), 
       (select count(*) from (select id from table) as cte2)
```

---

Unrelated, but: you might not be aware that `select (a,b)` is something different in Postgres then `select a,b`. The first returns a single column with an anonymous record type (that has two fields) and the second one returns two columns.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting! Also for the remark regarding `(a, b)` versus `a, b`, I did not really realize it when writing the question.

Comment: "The two CTEs are a single query so that query also doesn't see any (committed) changes done while its running." I've seen this claim in a couple of places on SO but I haven't been able to find an authoritative source (like a section or sentence in the PostgreSQL manual) that confirms it. Any pointers?

Comment: @AndresRiofrio: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED) "*When a transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (...) sees only data committed before the query began; it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed during query execution by concurrent transactions*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right, but that doesn't really make it clear whether that means each *root* SELECT query or each SELECT query, even subqueries. In fact, it seems to mean the latter to me.

Comment: A single statement is a single statement.

Comment: With RDBMSs, I've learned not to take anything for granted. 